# How to Display Lunar Phases Once a Month in Real Time Tracker Using If-Statements in JavaScript and Suncalc Library

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a real time lunar phase tracker using different algorithms and suncalc library in html,css and javascript.

So basically the website is displaying phases like full moon, new moon, first quarter, last quarter multiple times according to the phase index that is calculated but the fact is that these phases appear only once in a month. So, I was thinking if we could apply some if else conditions like:

new moon, full moon, first quarter and last quarter should be displayed at most once in a month

display full moon only if illumination is 100%

waxing gibbous is the previous phase of full moon and waning gibbous is the next phase of full moon

display full moon only if illumination is 0%

waning crescent is the previous phase of new moon and waxing crescent is the next phase of new moon

waxing crescent is the previous state of first quarter and waxing gibbous is the next phase of first quarter

waning gibbous is the previous state of last quarter and waning crescent is the next phase of last quarter

so i need help regarding that in the code

```js
function Lunar() {
  var self = this;

  /*
   * Creates a Moon object.
   *
   * @param {object} date A JavaScript Date object. If omitted, defaults to today.
   * @return {object} A Moon object
   *
   * 0 => new moon
   * 1 => waxing crescent
   * 2 => first quarter
   * 3 => waxing gibbous
   * 4 => full moon
   * 5 => waning gibbous
   * 6 => third quarter
   * 7 => waning crescent
   */
  this.Moon = function(config) {
    this.config = config || {};
    this.parent = self;

    this.init = function(date) {
      var jd;

      if (typeof date === 'number') {
        this.julianDay = date;
        this.date = new Date(this.parent.julianDayToUnixTimestamp(date));
      } else if (typeof date === 'object') {
        this.julianDay = this.parent.getJulianDay(date);
        this.date = date;
      } else {
        this.date = new Date();
        this.julianDay = this.parent.getJulianDay(this.date);
      }

      // Divide by the length of an average synodic month:
      jd = this.julianDay / 29.53;

      // Tip of the hat: http://voidware.com/moon_phase.htm
      this.phase = ((jd - Math.floor(jd)) * 8 + 0.5) & 7;
    };

    this.init(this.config.date);
  };

  /*
   * Converts a JS Date object into a Julian day.
   *
   * @param {object} date A JavaScript Date object (optional - defaults to today if omitted)
   * @return {number} The Julian date
   */
  this.getJulianDay = function(date) {
    var date = date || new Date();
    var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getUTCDate();
    var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var a = Math.floor((14 - month) / 12);
    var y = year + 4800 - a;
    var m = month + (12 * a) - 3;
    var jd = day + Math.floor((((153 * m) + 2) / 5));
    jd = jd + (365 * y);
    jd = jd + Math.floor(y / 4);
    jd = jd - Math.floor(y / 100);
    jd = jd + Math.floor(y / 400);
    jd = jd - 32045;
    return jd;
  };

  this.julianDayToUnixTimestamp = function(jd) {
    var EPOCH = 2440588;
    return (jd - EPOCH) * 86400000;
  };

  /*
   * @param {object} from A JavaScript Date object
   * @param {object} to A JavaScript Date object
   * @return {array} An array populated with one Moon object per day between 'from' and 'to'
   */
  this.getInterval = function(cfg) {
    var interval = [];
    var a = self.getJulianDay(new Date(cfg.from.year, (cfg.from.month - 1), cfg.from.day));
    var b = self.getJulianDay(new Date(cfg.to.year, (cfg.to.month - 1), cfg.to.day));

    // create one moon object per day
    // use Julian dates for super easy incrementing
    var x = a;
    for (x; x <= b; x++) {
      interval.push(new self.Moon({
        date: x
      }));
    }

    return interval;
  };
}

function calculateMoonPhase(date) {
  const lunar = new Lunar();
  const moon = new lunar.Moon({
    date: date
  });
  const phaseIndex = moon.phase;

  return phaseIndex;
}

function calculateMoonIllumination(date) {
  const lunar = new Lunar();
  const moon = new lunar.Moon({
    date: date
  })
  const moonIllumination = SunCalc.getMoonIllumination(date);
  const fraction = moonIllumination.fraction;
  const phaseIndex = moon.phase;
  const moonPercentage = Math.round(fraction * 100);

  return {
    phaseIndex: phaseIndex,
    fraction: fraction,
    percentage: moonPercentage
  };
}


function calculateDaysUntilFullMoon(date) {
  const moonIllumination = calculateMoonIllumination(date);

  // Calculate the number of days until the next full moon
  const daysUntilFullMoon = Math.round(moonIllumination.fraction * 29.53);
  return daysUntilFullMoon;
}

function calculateDaysUntilNewMoon(date) {
  const moonIllumination = calculateMoonIllumination(date);

  // Calculate the number of days until the next new moon
  const daysUntilNewMoon = Math.round((1 - moonIllumination.fraction) * 29.53);
  return daysUntilNewMoon;
}

function updateMoonPhaseElements(moonPhaseIndex, daysUntilFullMoon, daysUntilNewMoon, percentageIllumination) {
  const moonPhases = [
    'New Moon',
    'Waxing Crescent',
    'First Quarter',
    'Waxing Gibbous',
    'Full Moon',
    'Waning Gibbous',
    'Last Quarter',
    'Waning Crescent'
  ];

  const moonPhaseImageURL = 'images/' + moonPhaseIndex + '.jpg';

  const moonPhaseImage = document.getElementById('moon-image');
  const moonPhaseName = document.getElementById('moon-phase-name');
  const daysUntilFullMoonElement = document.getElementById('days-until-fullmoon');
  const daysUntilNewMoonElement = document.getElementById('days-until-newmoon');
  const percentageIlluminationElement = document.getElementById('percentage-illumination');

  moonPhaseImage.src = moonPhaseImageURL;
  moonPhaseName.textContent = moonPhases[moonPhaseIndex];
  daysUntilFullMoonElement.textContent = `Days Until Full Moon: ${daysUntilFullMoon}`;
  daysUntilNewMoonElement.textContent = `Days Until New Moon: ${daysUntilNewMoon}`;
  percentageIlluminationElement.textContent = `Percentage Illumination: ${percentageIllumination}%`;
}

function updateMoonPhase() {
  try {
    const today = new Date();
    const moonPhaseIndex = calculateMoonPhase(today);

    const moonIllumination = calculateMoonIllumination(today);

    const daysUntilFullMoon = calculateDaysUntilFullMoon(today);
    const daysUntilNewMoon = calculateDaysUntilNewMoon(today);
    const percentageIllumination = moonIllumination.percentage;

    updateMoonPhaseElements(moonPhaseIndex, daysUntilFullMoon, daysUntilNewMoon, percentageIllumination);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

updateMoonPhase();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/suncalc/1.8.0/suncalc.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="glass-box">
    <img id="moon-image" src="" alt="Moon Image">
    <div class="moon-info">
      <p id="moon-phase-name"></p>
      <p id="percentage-illumination"></p>
      <p id="days-until-fullmoon"></p>
      <p id="days-until-newmoon"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you mean by 'month' - the lunar cycle not being equal to the calendar month. Which is it? And what is your actual question?

Comment: basically i want some phases of moon to be displayed only once but they are being displayed more than once, for example next full moon is on 4 june but the website is showing full moon on 3 june, 4 june as well as 5 june so that issue needs to be corrected, same goes for other three phases: new moon, first quarter and last quarter

Comment: by month i mean the cycle that is considered to be of 29.53 days, the four phases i mentioned: full moon, new moon, first quarter and last quarter should appear only once in that duration which is currently not happening

Comment: You calculations return an integer so you will have the same values for multiple days. Maybe you can have it return a fractional part to be more precise when the moon phases happen. Possibly by removing `& 7` from `this.phase = ((jd - Math.floor(jd)) * 8 + 0.5) & 7;`.

Comment: Just a side note: I also have a moon phase display on my personal site. But instead of all that math, I just download the current phase from a website. (openweathermap.org which gives the moon phase as a value between `0` and `1` as well as a bunch of other info.)

Comment: Does it matter where you are in terms of on the globe (ie dateline stuff)?

Comment: that it for providing a value in range to determine the phaseindex, it is sure that if we are calculating the index it is totally possible that some values repeat but i want to restrict that by applying if else conditions that i mentioned above

Comment: @001 can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: no @AHaworth it doesn't